# Git local repository deleted when github project is deleted?

Tags: git, github

Yesterday I cloned a repo from github. I put some scripts in a subdirectory and started modifying those scripts, but without doing any commit.

Today, when I started my laptop, I was quite astonished to see that my local repo had disappeared. Checking on github, I saw that the remote repo was also gone.

How can a remote change can affect my local repo without any action from myself ? And how can I find back my local changes ?

Comment: Short answer : no. Github has (hopefully) no control on your hard disk storage. Are you positive the clone operation succeeded yesterday?

Comment: Yes I am positive. I guess the only explanation is that I removed the local repo accidentally, and that in the same time the github repo owner deleted the project.

Comment: Yes, that's my guess too :-/ I hope it's not too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside the mysterious disappearance of the local files, if you wish to ensure that others don't delete your repo you can create a fork of the original repo and work with that forked repository.

[image]

Help:

- [Forking Projects](https://guides.github.com/activities/forking/),
- [Fork a repo](https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo):

  > A fork is a copy of a repository. Forking a repository allows you to freely experiment with changes without affecting the original project.